# Page Won’t Allow Scrolling Down to See All Content on the Page

Tags: css, scroll

I have had a website for my track and cross country teams for a number of years now that I created with Dreamweaver about 5 or 6 years ago.  I recently decided it was time to update the website with a new look and feel.  However I’m running into problems I never had before creating web pages.  I’m wondering if using Dreamweaver CS6 versus whatever version I was using 5 or 6 years ago acts differently than what I did before that was so easy and gave me no problems creating pages.

I created a template from a blank template page and put a couple of rows of banners at the top with a table that is a row of images that will be links right below that.  My content will then go below the row of links where I put in an editable region.  I have the template set up and started working on my first page using that template, but I’m having a problem I can’t seem to resolve.  Whatever content I put in that editable region views just fine when I preview it in multiple browsers, except any content that drops below the bottom of the screen I can’t see and the page won’t scroll.  I have spent days trying to figure out how to get my page to scroll down to all of the content, but can’t figure out how to get it do this or if there is something in my CSS settings that is preventing my ability to scroll.  My banners at the type are set up in fixed positions so that they will always remain at the top of the page.  I’m wondering if this has something to do with the scroll issue?  I’ve seen people on here say using fixed settings is a bad way to go.  However, when I change them to relative I can’t get my banners to the top of the page where I want them and it messes up the look of the page.  In the past when I have designed webpages and I had content that required scrolling the page always automatically scrolled and I didn’t have to think about it.  I tried attaching the template and page using it, but I don’t think I can do that here, so I put the code below for the page I’ve created using the template.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
CTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Track and Field.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<style type="text/css">
#Content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 2in;
  height: 50in;
}
.style2 { color: #006699;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.style3 {
  color: #006699;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.style5 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #021480;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.style9 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #D48B68;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.style11 {color: #FFFFFF}
.style12 {color: #FFFF00; font-size: 12px; }
.style13 {color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; }
.style31 {color: #006699}
.style4 {font-size: 24px}
.style91 {font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; }
</style>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<style type="text/css">
#TFBannerPic {
  height: 1in;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0in;
  top: 0in;
  z-index: -100;
  /* [disabled]max-width: 1040px; */
}
#TFBanner {
  height: .5in;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 1in;
}
#Links {
  height: .5in;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0in;
  top: 1.5in;
}
#Content {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0in;
  top: 2.5in;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="Content">
<p><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Northwest-Track-Stadium-Banner.png" name="TFBannerPic" width="765" height="216" id="TFBannerPic" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Northwest-Track-Stadium-Banner.png" /></p>
<p><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Northwest-TF-Banner.png" name="TFBanner" width="994" height="66" id="TFBanner" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Northwest-TF-Banner.png" /></p>
<table width="106%" border="0" id="Links">
  <tr>
    <td width="83" bgcolor="#2A4D6E"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Home-Logo-Icon.png" width="79" height="65" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Home-Logo-Icon.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#728CA6"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Lion-Head-Logo.png" width="86" height="48" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Lion-Head-Logo.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#2A4D6E"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/May-Calendar.png" width="76" height="61" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/May-Calendar.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="91" bgcolor="#728CA6"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Coaching-Staff.png" width="87" height="52" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Coaching-Staff.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#d48b68"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Records.png" width="76" height="65" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Records.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#2A4D6E"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/History.png" width="66" height="66" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/History.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#FFEBA8"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Track-Events.png" width="82" height="66" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Track-Events.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#D48B68"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Tracks.png" width="79" height="66" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Tracks.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/In-The-News.png" width="79" height="75" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/In-The-News.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#FFEBA8"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Links.png" width="70" height="75" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Links.png" /></div></td>
    <td width="86" bgcolor="#D48B68"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Web%20Background/Alumni.png" width="83" height="59" longdesc="../Graphics/Web Background/Alumni.png" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Content" -->
<div align="center" id="Content">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center" class="style5" id="style5">Track and Field Events</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><p class="style3" id="style3">There are 12 running events and 6 field events in a normal high school track meet in Missouri. In addition, there are an additional 5 relay events, 1 field event, and 1 multi-event that are contested at some meets, but are not normal high school events in Missouri-these are listed in italics. Below is a description and diagram of each event. To jump to a particular event click on the event below. </p>
      <p class="style3"></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="50%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#100m">100m Dash </a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><em><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#4x1600">4 x 1600m Relay</a></span></em></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#200m">200m Dash</a></span></div></td>
      <td width="50%"><div align="center"><em><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#sprintmedley">Sprint Medley Relay (800m)</a></span></em></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#400m">400m Dash </a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><em><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#distancemedley">Distance Medley Relay (4,000m)</a></span></em></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#800m">800m Run </a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><em><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#1600medley">1600m Sprint Medley Relay</a></span></em></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#1600m">1600m Run </a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#longjump">Long Jump </a></span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#3200m">3200m Run </a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#triplejump">Triple Jump </a></span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#100h">100m Hurdles</a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#highjump">High Jump </a></span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#300h">300m Hurdles</a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#polevault">Pole Vault </a></span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#hurdlerelay"><em>Shuttle Hurdle Relay </em></a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#shotput">Shot Put </a></span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#4x100">4 x 100m Relay</a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#discus">Discus</a></span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#4x200">4 x 200m Relay </a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><em><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#pentathlon">Pentathlon</a></span></em></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#4x400">4 x 400m Relay</a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><em><span class="style3">Javelin</span></em></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><span class="style3"><a href="events.htm#4x800">4 x 800m Relay</a></span></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="90%"  border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="style31"><div align="center" class="style4"><a name="100m" id="100m"></a>100m Dash </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="style2">The 100m is the classic sprints race distance. The reigning 100m world record holder is often named &quot;the fastest man/woman in the world&quot;, and the 100 m Olympic title is usually considered among the most prestigious. This 100m is the domain of absolute speed. Athletes of all builds can do well at this distance. Being fast means being able to transmit the orders needed for muscular contraction instantly from the brain. When the gun fires, athletes must react with adrenaline-charged urgency. The 100m demands exceptional reflexes at the start and great explosive power. In the first few strides sprinters must have perfect control of movement and balance without &quot;tightening up&quot;. Then they must use their acceleration skills to reach top speed. Since it is difficult to maintain top speed after 6 to 7 seconds of effort, sprinters need strong muscles and relaxed technique. Maintaining the right balance between frequency and length of stride is the key to sprint technique. The 100m can be broken down into basic phases of start, pick-up and finish. The right blend gets results. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="style2">World Record: 10.49-Florence Griffith Joyner-United States-July 16, 1988</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="style2">American Record: 10.49-Florence Griffith Joyner-United States-July 16, 1988</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="style2">U.S. High School Record: 11.11-Angela Williams (Chino H.S., Chino, CA)-1998</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="style2">Missouri State Record: 11.66-Muna Lee (Kansas City Central H.S.)-1999 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="style2">Northwest School Record: 12.29-Chandra Chilges-1992</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><div align="center"><img src="Graphics/Helpers/Events/100m.jpg" alt="100m Dash" width="360" height="306" /></div></td>
      <td align="left" class="style3"><div align="center">Florence Griffith Joyner's 100m World Record:</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center">
        <object width="340" height="285" align="absmiddle">
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
          <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
          <param name="Flo Jo 100m" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Kg_ypZ5kBcI&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x5d1719&amp;color2=0xcd311b&amp;border=1" />
          <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Kg_ypZ5kBcI&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x5d1719&amp;color2=0xcd311b&amp;border=1" width="340" height="285" align="absmiddle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
        </object>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: At a quick glance, removing the `position: relative;` from the `#Content` CSS will allow page scrolling.. but there are many other issues with this page.. for example `id="Content"` is used multiple times, Ids should be unique, if you would like to apply the same css to multiple elements use `class=` instead. This goes for the CSS as well as the Html.

Comment: Jake, thanks for you reply.  I took your advice and I took out the id=“Content”.  I think I have it multiple times because I have not been able to get things to work like I wanted.  I created a class tag instead.   More importantly I removed the position:  relative for my editable region of the page.  The problem now however when I do that is that I am not able to restrict my body content in that editable region from staying below the banner.  Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the [position: CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) is incorrect for what you are describing. Remove all of the `position:` css attributes and the page should begin to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you Jake!  As you said, once I took out all positioning the page works!  I appreciate your help!